# Setting up Artifactory in gradle global

Tags: gradle, publish, artifactory

currently I have a project which is deploying artifacts in our artifactory. For that Project everything is setted up perfect and it works.

I just wonderd if there is a possibility to set up the whole artifactory configuration global in gradle, so that I don't have to write the artifactory {...} stuff for each project.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write your own **Gradle plugin** that would be responsible for:

- applying the *artifactory plugin* and other related plugin(s) like *maven-publish*
- provide default values for the `artifactory` extension properties , like `contextUrl`, `repoKey`, credentials, etc...

Then your different projects will just have to apply your custom plugin, and provide only the project-specific configuration (configuration of the artefact to be published, for example, in `publishing` extension)

**EDIT** there are other ways to implement that, but it depends on what you mean by "global in gradle":

- global to your own computer?  then you could create a User [InitScript](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script) that would contain the *artifactory plugin* configuration part
- global to your team/company ? then you could need to implement a custom plugin, and maybe include this plugin into a custom *gradle wrapper* distribution (see [example here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/10/gradle-goodness-distribute-custom.html)

**EDIT2** If you just want to set the *artifactory plugin* configuration of different sub-project of a same multi-project build, then the simpliest solution would be to define this configuration in the `subprojects` block of the *root project* build script:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

    artifactory {
        publish {
            contextUrl = '<repo url>'
            repository {
                repoKey = "<repo name>"
                username = "user"
                password = "pass"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a file lets say build_dependency.gradle and define the task for all project

```
 allprojects
 {
 //task common for all the project
 }

subprojects
{
//task for subprojects
}
```

or specify the type of project e.g `ext.warProject = 1` in dependency file  and refer it in build_dependency.gradle as

```
if(project.hasProperty('warProject '))
 {
  //task here
 }
```

and use this file in build.gradle like `apply from: "$rootDir/path_to_file/build_dependency.gradle"`
"$rootDir/path_to_dependenccy_file"`

Comment: I was the thinking about writing an own plugin. What I don't like about it is that the jfrog artifactory plugin needs to be loaded in every build.gradle file from each project, even when the apply plugin is inside my own plugin.

Comment: See the other answer I proposed about writting a plugin.. I don't exactly undertand what you mean by "artifactory plugin needs to be loaded in every build.gradle from each project":  if you implement your own plugin that automatically applies and configure the Artifactory plugin, you don't need to apply artifactory plugin anymore in your different projects.  just need to apply our own plugin.

Comment: What I figured out is that I need to load the jfrog plugin by adding `plugin { id: org.jfrog.artifactroy} ` to the build file.
As far as I know this part needs to be placed in the `build.gradle` file and can not be placed in the plugin.
So to apply a plugin has to look something like:

`plugin { id: org.jfrog. … id: my_plugin} plugin aply: myplugin`


So even that your not applying the jfrog plugin you need to define it in the `build.gradle`.

Comment: You can use a task in build.gradle  ext.definedTask =1 and definition should be like if(project.hasProperty('definedTask '))  { `apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
    artifactory {
         publish    {
                contextUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory'
                repository {
                                 repoKey = "libs-snapshot-local"
                                 username = "user"
                                 password = "pass"
                            }
                   }
             } }`